# Filter stringset that contain string with substring?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

My column value is a string set, how do i filter string set with string that contain a substring

For example

entry1 :

```
{
  ss : [
    "TRUE_item",
    "FALSE_item"
  ]
}
```

entry2 :

```
{
  ss : [
    "FASE_item",
    "FALSE_item"
  ]
}
```

How to i filter entry wihich contain `ss` that have an element contain `TRUE`, which in this case should return entry 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. You must give the entire value to match a string within a set.